# If in switch method, asking for constant value

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm having a problem with finding the constant value with this code:

```
var size = q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees.Text;

        switch (size)
        {
            case:
                if (int.Parse(size) > 5 && int.Parse(size) < 15)
                {
                    Rect1.Height = Rect1.ActualHeight - 10;
                    Rect1.Width = Rect1.ActualWidth - 5;
                }
                break;
        }
```

any ideas? there were supposed to be multiple cases, for the record!

Comment: That's what `if`-statements are for.

Comment: Why do you need `switch` here if you check size inside `case` statement?

Comment: Case values in C# 6 must be a constant value, something that doesn't change. If you want the same effect as a case statement, consider multiple if/if else statements instead of a switch.

Comment: because its kinda of an exploration, and i need 15 if's.

Comment: @mason so i cannot use switch for multiple if's when this is the case?
i could do that, just was thinking if i could put all if's in a switch.

Comment: Correct, you can't do an if statement in a switch. Nor do you need to do. Just do an if statement, and multiple if/else statements instead.

Comment: @mason Ty for your patience and advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case values in C# 6 must be a constant value, something that doesn't change. If you want the same effect as a case statement, consider multiple if/if else statements instead of a switch.

```
var size = q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees.Text;

if (int.Parse(size) > 5 && int.Parse(size) < 15)
{
    Rect1.Height = Rect1.ActualHeight - 10;
    Rect1.Width = Rect1.ActualWidth - 5;
}
```

Above is the valid version of your code. You could also add additional if/else statements that would function similarly to case statements.

```
if (int.Parse(size) > 5 && int.Parse(size) < 15)
{
    Rect1.Height = Rect1.ActualHeight - 10;
    Rect1.Width = Rect1.ActualWidth - 5;
}
else if(some other condition)
{
    ...
}
else if(some other condition again)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    //if no other conditions are satisfied, this gets executed.
    //it's like the default case in a switch statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign cases values like `case "foo":` or `case 15:`.

Comment: i tried with 1, 2, 3 then it says i cannot convert type int to bool.

Comment: First, you don't need switch here. Only one case happens. Please rebiuld this to be only if-structured. Switch is unnecesary as far as I can see.
Otherwise, you didn't design problem properly. You expect many cases but for now they can't even happen.

Comment: @JohnOsik Why would there be one case?

Comment: Because switch isn't really `size` based.

Comment: Of course it is. size can be any value, it is a string. It can have anything. We dont know.

Comment: So basically `if` is `size` based. Switch itself just happens with the only defined case with no constant.

Comment: @CodingYoshi  well, would it break if i used case "1", case "2" etc. because it isnt giving me any errors? i havent tested it yet though

Comment: We use switch if we expect some discrete values. Otherwise it's better to stay with if and test ranges.